# Why are kbd tags disabled in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I just realized that `<kbd></kbd>` tags don't work in comments (<kbd>KeyName</kbd>). Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: I don't think any HTML is allowed in comments. <br> See, the `<br>` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  `[link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** \`code\``. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@peter` or `@PeterSmith` will both work. [Learn more...](http://meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 4):

Comments support fewer features because they are definitely [second class citizens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) in the Stack Exchange world.